How to show jumbled numberical keypad in android?
I want to show a numeric keyboard for my TextField but I want the numbers to be jumbled up every time. I have seen this in some apps but I don't think there is a native support for this (correct me if I am wrong). What's the direction I should be looking into for this solution?

There's no built-in way to directly create a jumbled numerical keypad in Android. You should explore open-source libraries that might offer pre-built solutions for jumbled keypads.

You will have to create your own keypad for that, or try looking for an open source library that offers this.
